# How to run Pyramid and Websocket on a Apache httpd Server?

Tags: apache, websocket, pyramid

I am trying to build a website with Pyramid. This project is require to act as a Websocket server waiting and answering Websocket connections. And also, we have to deploy this website on a WSGI-enabled Apache httpd server. Is this possible? How to make Pyramid support Websocket? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure it helps, but you might want to check pyramid_socketio.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, AFAIK. You can use pyramid_socketio https://github.com/abourget/pyramid_socketio but this dont work with a frontend.